# Alinhar imagens lado a lado grid bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Quero alinhar elementos no grid, mas ele ficam um em cima do outro quando coloco.

Tentei usar `float: left`, a princípio funciona, mas quando a tela fica pequena fica tudo bagunçado, as imagens ficam fora da `div`.

Segue o código de exemplo:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" style="border:1px solid red;">                
    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Imagens</b></p>                

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left " width="50px"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" style="border:1px solid red;">                
    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Imagens</b></p>                

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left " width="50px"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suas imagens estão com a classe `pull-left`, que utiliza `float: left` fazendo com que suas imagens não estejam no fluxo de elementos do HTML.

Para arrumar você pode colocar a classe `clearfix` nos containers ([Documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix)).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->

<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 clearfix" style="border:1px solid red;">                
    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Imagens</b></p>                

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left " width="50px"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
</div>


<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1  clearfix" style="border:1px solid red;">                
    <p style="text-align:center;"><b>Imagens</b></p>                

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left " width="50px"> 
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/" class="img-responsive pull-left" width="50px">
</div>
```